# Router used as ethernet bridge wont show up

Tags: router, ethernet

I have a Netgear router in my living room that has the wireless signal. It is connected to a Powerline plug that goes up to my bedroom. That is plugged into another router that is used as an ethernet hub. It's cables go into my PS3 and my server. The second router shows up as a hidden network on my laptop, and I can connect to it. But it is not listed as an attached device on my main router, and my laptop says that it connects straight to the main router, not the second one.

How can I connect to this router? Aside from swapping the two?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you've got a router that's a bridge and a router that's a hub (?!?)... do you happen to have a router that's a *router* anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want more than one router in a LAN if you can avoid it. In you case, the best fix is to make sure all routers but the one that does your actual routing (the one that connects to your Internet access) are being used only as switches or bridges.

To use a router as a switch or bridge, turn off its DHCP server. Do not use its Internet or WAN port, only connect to its LAN ports. Make sure it's LAN IP address is an unused IP address inside your LAN IP subnet that is outside of the main router's DHCP range.

So, for example, your main router could be set as a DHCP server and connected to your Internet connection with a LAN IP address of 192.168.1.1 and a DHCP range of .100 - .200 while your other routers are 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3. The other routers should have their DHCP servers disabled and their WAN/Internet ports unconnected.